# Python способ парсинга ответов от сервера

Tags: python

Перед мной стала такая задача, необходимо написать парсилку, которая в зависимости от запроса сервера будет вызывать определенную функцию.
Все до чего я пока дошел это древо из ифов, но я уверен есть более красивый способ реализации

```
 if key == ['0000', '1115']:
        return self.ok_answer()
    elif key == '0a00':
        return self.wifi_answer(message.sender)
    elif key == '115':
...
```

Comment: попробуйте перенести это в словарь. `dict = {'0000': self.ok_answer}` и использовать доступ по ключу `dict[key]`

Comment: Однако интересно выходит с диктами, во время итерации по словарю, если поместить на место значения функцию и ее вызов - пайтон выполнит эту функцию, не смотря на то что ключ не подходит..

Comment: а зачем по нему итерироваться и тем более вызывать функцию?) вы можете поместить в словарь функцию не вызывая её и если в словаре будет нужный вам ключ то взять по нему эту функцию и уже потом вызвать